# First clEnqueueMapBuffer call takes much time

Tags: c, performance, memory-management, gpu, opencl

I have a performance issue in YOLO adoption for OpenCL code.

The method, which just pulls data from device, works slow first time and fast next several calls. There is log with calls, time in microseconds:

```
clEnqueueMapBuffer      144469
memcpy  2
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject 31
clEnqueueMapBuffer      466
memcpy  103
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject 14
clEnqueueMapBuffer      468
memcpy  106
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject 17
```

First call is with 1 byte copy (where memcpy takes 2 microseconds).

The memory is allocated by code:

```
if (!x)
    x = (float*) calloc(n, sizeof(float));

buf.ptr = x;

cl_int clErr;
buf.org = clCreateBuffer(opencl_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | 
CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, buf.len * buf.obs, buf.ptr, &clErr);
```

The code for pulling data is next:

```
#ifdef BENCHMARK
    clock_t t;
    double time_taken;
    t = clock();
#endif
    cl_int clErr;
    void* map = clEnqueueMapBuffer(opencl_queues[opencl_device_id_t], x_gpu.mem, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ,
                                   0, x_gpu.len * x_gpu.obs, 0, NULL, NULL, &clErr);
#ifdef BENCHMARK
    t = clock() - t;
    time_taken = ((double)t);
    printf("clEnqueueMapBuffer\t%d\n", (int)time_taken);
    t = clock();
#endif
    if (clErr != CL_SUCCESS)
        printf("could not map array to device. error: %s\n", clCheckError(clErr));
    memcpy(x, map, (n - x_gpu.off) * x_gpu.obs);
#ifdef BENCHMARK
    t = clock() - t;
    time_taken = ((double)t);
    printf("memcpy\t%d\n", (int)time_taken);
    t = clock();
#endif
    clErr = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(opencl_queues[opencl_device_id_t], x_gpu.mem, map, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (clErr != CL_SUCCESS)
        printf("could not unmap array from device. error: %s\n", clCheckError(clErr));
#ifdef BENCHMARK
    t = clock() - t;
    time_taken = ((double)t);
    printf("clEnqueueUnmapMemObject\t%d\n", (int)time_taken);
#endif
```

What could be the reason of such delay during first call? How to decrease the delay?

Comment: Are you certain any previous operations on the command queue, such as enqueued kernels, have finished by the time you call `clEnqueueMapBuffer()`? If unsure, try inserting `clFinish()` before the mapping. (Generally, the `clFinish()` is not needed and not having it there is potentially faster, but asynchronously queued commands will cause misleading time measurements without it.)

Comment: The other possibility is simply that the implementation is copying the data from GPU VRAM to host memory, and this will take time. In this case, you may wish to experiment with removing the `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` flag on buffer creation, and/or to use [clEnqueueReadBuffer()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadBuffer.html) to get the GPU's DMA controller to perform the copy. (If you're just using memcpy to copy all the data out, there's not really much point in using the mapping API - the idea of that is to allow direct, zero-copy access.)

Comment: You are right. There were unfinished operations. Calling clFinish() takes all time:

clFinish        148326
clEnqueueMapBuffer      155

Comment: Cool, I've posted an answer explaining this in a little more detail. Hope that all makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `clEnqueueMapBuffer()` call is blocking (`CL_TRUE` for the `blocking_map` parameter) which means that the call will only return once the mapping operation has *completed*. If your command queue is not concurrent, any previously queued, asynchronous commands such as enqueued kernels, will need to complete before the mapping *can even begin*. If there are such earlier commands, you are actually measuring their completion as well as the memory-mapping operation. To avoid this, add a `clFinish()` call before starting your clock. (It is possibly slightly more efficient *not* to call `clFinish()`, so I recommend you only leave it in for measurement purposes.)